# What is the difference between 'hallar' and 'encontrar'?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos, diferencias-entre-palabras

If I find something I lost, should I use 'hallar'?

For example, I found missing keys and said to my wife:

> "¡**Hallé** las llaves!"
>   "¿Las **encontraste**?" —she replied—.

Then a discussion about 'hallar' vs 'encontrar' began.

Comment: Prácticamente sinónimos. Me gusta pensar que puedes encontrar una cosa por casualidad (originalmente se refería a salir al encuentro), y puedes hallar una cosa que estabas buscando. Véase la etimología de [hallar](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?hallar)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My knowledge of Spanish is old school so I have found that the meaning of some things have changed. "Hallar" and "Encontrar" are basically synonyms but in the most proper Mexican Spanish. "Hallar" implies knowing where something is, whereas "Encontrar" means you have what you where looking for. Exp:

> "¡Hallé mis llaves! Se las llevó María." (I found my keys, Mary took them.)
>
> "¡Encontré mis llaves! Estaban en el sofá." (I found my keys, they were in the sofa.)

"Halla" and Hallar" have the same root so you say:

> "Hallé una nube que parece un pato." (I found a cloud that looks like a duck.)

"Encontré" can be used, but properly because the clouds are at a distance, "Hallar" is more fitting.

Answer (score 10):

In Argentine Spanish, *hallar* and *encontrar* are exact synonyms, although *hallar* is not used often, just formally, as in news or papers.
*Hallazgo* is used though, meaning *finding* (as noun)

Also, both words have alternative meanings when used in reflexive*:
*no me hallo* meaning I don't fit, or I don't feel comfortable in a certain situation.
*me encuentro aquí* meaning *I am here*, but it's kind of formal.

* It's pretty common in Spanish that reflexive verbs have an alternative meaning than the original verb. E.G. *ver* = to see, *ver**se*** = to look (as in *you look good*)

Comment: I've seen *hallazgo* used for a scientific discovery.

Comment: @aparente001 yes, they are **kinda** synonyms, discovery, finding.

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, I'd say that *hallar* means *to find* (as result of searching), while *encontrar* has a wider meaning, it's more like *to find* including finding by chance or *to encounter*, as in the meaning *to meet* someone. However, random finding could be still described as *hallazgo*.

Comment: You are correct *hallar" implied that you where searching where "Encontre" does not." "Allazgo" still works because it suggest something you have always wanted. I forgot to put this in my answer. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

At least in my country, Spain, they mean exactly the same. Even one of the definitions of "encontrar" in the official spanish dictionary has the word "hallar" in it.

Even tough, the main difference relies on the fact that you can found "hallar" in formal contexts, like scientific papers, and "encontrar" is colloquial.

Comment: Mmm but in Spain we would say 'me encuentro mal' (I feel sick), while 'me hallo mal' is never used in this context. Don't you think so?

Comment: Wow. True. I didn't thought about that case, but you are definitely right.

Comment: No se encuentra. [no está en casa]. No se diria: no se halla. Encontrar is not colloquial, what an idea.

Comment: @fedorqui 'SO stop harming' Esto me lo encontré en el DLE bajo la entrada de **hallar**: "*9. prnl. Encontrarse en cierto estado.* ***Hallarse*** *atado, perdido, alegre,* ***enfermo***"

Comment: @nopaltepec interesante, a mí no me suena idiomático, pero bien puede serlo en otras zonas o países.